# Como limpar a tela em C++?

Tags: c++, tela

Como limpar a tela em C++ ?
Já coloquei a bibilioteca: ** #include< stdlib.h>** e o código: **system("cls")**, mas da o erro: "**sh: 1: cls: not found**". Como resolvo isto?

Answer (score 5):

Apagar a tela é uma operação dependente do ambiente em que o programa opera. Por exemplo, um programa gráfico não nem tem esta operação, porque não está rodando num terminal.

Dito isto, parece que você está executando o programa num ambiente UNIX/Linux, então sugiro substituir "cls" por "clear", pois "cls" é a instrução de linha de comando do MS-DOS/Windows para limpar a tela.

Answer (score 2):

Como já dito, depende do ambiente, no entanto como sugerido já temo o comando:

```
clear
```

Que é usado geralmente em sistemas unix-like (linux por exemplo) e o comando:

```
cls
```

Usado em sistemas Windows.

Se o erro ocorre talvez seja porque esta executando `cls` em um sistema Linux (ou semelhante).

Para criar uma 'certa compatibilidade' entre diferentes sistemas pode ser um pouco complexo, há quem sugere usar as definições do compilador, por exemplo (é um exemplo bem simplório):

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    system("cls");
#else defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__)
    system("clear");
#endif
```

Mas isto claro talvez varie muito pra cada compilador, ou seja talvez os compiladores ou libs disponíveis usem outras definições para identificar o sistema que foi compilado, então uma sugestão que creio que seria mais garantida seria usar no próprio comando o **`||`** e com isto passar ambos comandos (`cls` e `clear`), por exemplo:

```
system("clear||cls");
```

O comando acima vai executar assim, primeiro ele tenta executar o `clear`, se for um comando disponível no sistema do usuário então ele será executado, caso contrário vai tentar executar `cls`.

Isto pode tornar seu programa um pouco mais "portável" entre diferentes sistemas sem se preocupar tanto com diferentes tipos de compiladores.