# Como apagar o terminal do que foi escrito quando executa um programa em C?

Tags: c, c++

Pessoal estou com uma duvida tremenda. Quando executo um programa em C ele mostra as informações que estão no terminal. Mas depois quero apagar o que foi escrito para mostra uma nova informação. Já fiz umas pesquisas e não encontrei nada que solucione esse problema. Já tentei algumas coisas que encontrei, mas não tive resultado. Sou novo em programação e estou fazendo um trabalho pra faculdade <- não vale nota, mas queria deixar o programa com uma boa visibilidade.
OBS: NÃO FINALIZEI TODA A ATIVIDADE AINDA.
Desde já agradeço. obrigado!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int somar (){

    return 2+5;
}

int main() { //O algoritmo é pra executar uma serie de atividades usando função
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

  int n, funcao;
  char caso;

do{

  printf ("\n ******************************************");
  printf ("\n **    Escolha abaixo uma das opções   **\n");
  printf (" ******************************************\n\n");

  printf (" ----> Atividade 1 = digite (1)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 2 = digite (2)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 3 = digite (3)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 4 = digite (4)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 5 = digite (5)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 6 = digite (6)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 7 = digite (7)\n");
  printf (" ----> Atividade 8 = digite (8)\n\n");

  scanf ("%s", &caso);

  //após a escolha da opção quero que saia da tela o que está escrito acima do comentario

switch (caso) {
    case '1':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

    case '2':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

    case '3':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

     case '4':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

    case '5':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

    case '6':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

    case '7':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;

    case '8':
        funcao=somar();
        printf ("%d", funcao);
        break;


    default: printf ("\n\t**********OPÇÃO ERRADA**********");
  }

  printf ("\n\n\nDeseja fazer outra oeração?\n\n--->Digite 0 para sim.\n--->Digite qualquer numero para sair.\n");
  scanf ("%d", &n);
} while (n==0); //ao final do do-while também quero que apague tudo o que foi escrito
// pra quando iniciar novamente o programa inicie limpinho o terminal.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te ajudaria: [Como limpar a tela em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290972/como-limpar-a-tela-em-c)

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo. Eu ja tinha encontrado esse post anteriormente, mas dava erro de compilação. Quando tentei **system("clear||cls");** junto com a biblioteca **#include <stdlib.h>** funcionou. Anteriormente só tentei *system("clear");*

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como limpar a tela em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290972/como-limpar-a-tela-em-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limpar a tela em C é um assunto bem controverso. Você tem várias maneiras de fazer isso para o ponto de vista do usuário, porém eu nunca vi um consenso entre os programadores, devido à falta de portabilidade. Como é uma atividade da faculdade, eu recomendaria não tentar métodos muito elaborados, pois seria difícil fazer uma explicação destes.

Para Windows você pode incluir a biblioteca stdlib.h e usar o comando system("cls"):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system("cls");
```

O equivalente em Linux seria:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system("clear");
```

Outra maneira seria usando bibliotecas como a "conio" para Windows e a "ncurses" para Linux.

```
#include <conio.h>

clrscr();
```

Não vou colocar aqui a maneira usando a ncurses pois já tive alguns problemas, e não quero te induzir a fazer coisas que não funcionem.
Além destes métodos citados, existem outros inúmeros, porém mais elaborados. Não recomendo usá-los em seu trabalho. Vou dar alguns exemplos.

Você pode usar a biblioteca windows.h para pegar as dimensões do terminal, e imprimir quantos "espaços" forem necessários, ou mesmo quanas quebras de linha.

```
#include <windows.h>

int get_cmd_nrows(){
   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
   GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
   return(csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1);
}
int get_cmd_ncols(){
   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
   GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
   return(csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1);
}
void clear1() { //método com espaços
   int i, r, c;
   r = get_cmd_nrows();
   c = get_cmd_ncols();
   for(i = 0;i<r*c;i++) {
       printf(" ");
   }
}
void clear2() {
   int i, r; //Método usando quebras de linha
   r = get_cmd_nrows();
   for(i = 0;i<r ;i++) {
       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Veja, que já começa a ficar bem mais abstrato. Aqui vai mais um exemplo que funciona em sistemas baseados em Linux (Por utilizarem um terminal que condiz com tais caracteres).

Primeiro defina o caractere de escape ("\033[") e depois o caractere CLEAR, que será usado na nossa função clear(). H para voltar o cursor para a origem, e J para limpar a tela. Depois disso, basta printar esse código na tela. Ou fazer desse modo:

```
#define ESC             "\033["
#define CLEAR           ESC "H" ESC "J"

void eval(const char * cd) {
   printf("%s", cd);
}

void clear() {
   eval(CLEAR);
}
```

A partir daí, basta chamar a função clear(). Enfim, existem outras maneiras, porém acredito que tenha dado para entender a proposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, já entreguei para o professor corrigir. Mas assim que eu fazer mais coisas em programação C. Vou usar essas técnicas diferentes que você me passou. Vou até testar agora. Vlww

Answer (score 0):

Usar `system()` para fazer algo não é de fato fazer algo em um programa. E é algo condenado ou proibido em muitos lugares por questões de segurança. É como alguém te perguntar o caminho para uma rua e você fazer cara de intelectual e dizer como procurar no Maps do Google. :D

No windows o oficial para limpar a "tela", que por padrão tem 9001 linhas, é algo assim em `C` ou `C++`

```
int     cls()
{   // limpa a tela no windows, do jeito oficial
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO      info;
    HANDLE      H = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD       origem = { 0,0 };
    int         total;
    if (H == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return -1;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(H, &info);
    int r = FillConsoleOutputCharacter(H, (TCHAR)' ',
        info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y,
        origem, &total);
    int s = FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        H, info.wAttributes,
        info.dwSize.X * info.dwSize.Y,
        origem, &total);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(H, origem);
    return 0;
};  // end cls()
```

E a lógica é a descrita em [A Biblia da Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference)

Você consegue um handle para acessar a janela da console, chama `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()` para ver o tamanho atual da janela e as rotinas acima para preencher a área toda com espaços e com o atributo em uso. E deve "limpar" mesmo o atributo ou mudanças anteriores de cor ou negrito por exemplo podem aparecer de novo.

#### Um pouco de história

No Unix/Linux/Mac não existe esse conceito de console. Os programas escrevem no "terminal" usando um emulador. De terminal. O modelo de programação do Unix é dos anos 70. O do Windows dos anos 80. :) No Unix os terminais eram assim, terminais. Com tomada, fonte, teclado e uma porta serial. E era um inferno porque cada marca era de um jeito.

Com o passar do tempo a coisa evoluiu para um modelo baseado em uma estrutura chamada `terminfo` que ainda existe hoje. E é uma referência de comandos para o terminal.

No geral os comandos usados são uma herança dos comandos dos terminais da Digital, em especial os VT-52 e VT-100 e VT-240. Comandos que começam por ESC[ e são centenas deles. O Linux não tem memória da tela, as letras eram enviadas pelo sistema uma a uma pela porta serial. Uma maneira conhecida de limpar a tela era DESLIGAR o terminal e ligar de novo. Velhos tempos. A outra mais moderna era acessar terminfo e ver quantas linhas tinha o terminal, e aí escrever tantos `return`/`line feed` quantas linhas tenha o terminal, "limpando a tela" porque o terminal não tem memória ou scroll.

Um dos comandos mais poderosos do `terminfo` é o `reset` e você pode rodar em seu terminal um ``tput reset `e vai ser o equivalente a ligar e desligar o terminal, limpando a tela`. tput reset é o que faz o comando `clear`, até onde eu sei.

Não ter a imagem da tela é um inferno e por isso *curses* era tão útil. hoje em dia os emuladores `tty` tem scroll e memória, mas o modelo de programação em nada mudou. *ncurses* ainda é o caminho mais curto se precisa poder usar janelas de texto e coisas mais sofisticadas, sem interface gráfica: ncurses tem janelas sobrepostas, imagem da tela, trata bem o teclado, otimiza o uso do display e seu modelo de programação é bem simples.

#### A "nova" console do Windows

No entanto, a partir de 2018, a Microsoft tem gasto uma fortuna implementando o modelo de programação do Linux para a console do Windows e agora tudo está ainda mais confuso. [Mais sobre isso aqui, direto da Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/)

O que acontece é que com a migração dos computadores aos milhões para a nuvem, na contramão da migração dos anos 80 quando as aplicações começaram a sair dos mainframes para os minicomputadores e depois para os computadores pessoais, agora tudo está voltando para a tal nuvem. E os computadores não tem interface gráfica e a administração é em muitos casos via texto. E aí um modelo único de programação faz todo sentido.

Eu ia continuar escrevendo mas acho que ninguém vai ler e estou me afastando do tópico...

O tal novo modelo está descrito aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions